# CSS not working in PHP-version of (identical) HTML page

Tags: php, html, css

I have a HTML file styled with external CSS. It works fine but when I change the HTML file to PHP (with the same code), the CSS seems not working with my PHP file.

The files are almost exactly identical, and they look like this:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jqueryactions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/mousetrail.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content here -->
    </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​
```

The full code of the HTML and of the CSS, and a `diff` between the HTML-version and the PHP-version can be found on pastebin:

- [Full HTML](http://pastebin.com/GY01NERt)
- [Full CSS](http://pastebin.com/bYurTvTt)
- [`diff` between HTML and PHP](http://pastebin.com/rbjrpqpj)

As you can see, the HTML and PHP code are the same. But they give different output. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Your PHP file doesn't have <html> at the very beginning?

Comment: Are the files placed in the same directory? Try using: 
<link href="/css/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> to include your stylesheet instead

Comment: Is there really `<?include('try.php');?>` in your HTML file ?

Comment: Also, do add a <!DOCTYPE html> if you want an HTML 5 DOCTYPE.
Or any other DOCTYPE you want to use.
As a general principle, you include HTML files in php files, not the other way around. If you want stuff rendered at server level that is.

Comment: Is your PHP-version missing the opening `<html>` and `<head>` tags, or did that get lost while posting the question?

Comment: @PPvG no, it was a SO format issue.  It was there, I just edited it to fix that issue but will have to wait for others to approve the edit before it shows up.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Are none of the CSS stylings being applied, or only a subset of them?  When you debug in your browser, is the CSS file found/loaded?  Continuing to debug in your browser, are styles from that CSS being applied to the target elements?  You can't just dump your code here and expect miracles, you need to do a little debugging.

Comment: Show us a screenshot. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: This needs some basic quality assurance first: 1.) Does your websites' HTML validate? 2.) Do you get 404 for any link in there? 3.) Is the CSS valid? 4.) Is the javascript valid? 5.) Is the by javascript modified DOM still valid HTML?

Comment: oh sorry i never notice that ... i just lose the head and html tags while posting ...but you can just refer to the html file because they are thesame except for the 'include' in php

Answer (score 1):

> the html and php code are thesame but they give different output

This isn't entirely true.  A PHP will be processed by the PHP interpreter when a HTML won't (by standard/traditional setups).

If you have PHP code in your file, it could have a syntax error which might cause things to not load properly.

With that said, the only PHP code I see is:

```
<?include('try.php');?>
```

I'm guessing this could be the problem.  Try these steps in troubleshooting:

1. Change your code to PHP 5 compliance by adding "php" after the first '?' along with an extra space between `<?php include...` like so:

   ```
   <?php include('try.php'); ?>
   ```

   Refresh the page to see if that worked.  If it did, it's a syntax issue with your version of PHP.
2. Comment out the PHP code to see if the PHP page will run as straight HTML.

   ```
   <?php //include('try.php'); ?>
   ```

   If this did the trick, there's likely an issue in the `try.php` file that's causing the issue.

Try those troubleshooting steps to see if that helps. And, as Alex FI points out, add a `DocType` to your HTML.

I hope that helps!